# Unsatisfied version 0 from shell of shared singleton module firebase/messaging (required ^9.17.1) at getStrictSingletonVersion

Tags: angular, firebase, webpack, angular-module-federation, module-export

Basically i want to add Firebase on my Angular app. I am using NX Module Federation and after i do `npm i firebase` i get the error above. I have one package.json for all microservices and shell together so there can't be version mismatch, i guess?
Versions: Angular 15.0, Firebase 9.17.1, @firebase/messaging 0.12.1

## webpack.config.js

```
const { withModuleFederation } = require('@nrwl/angular/module-federation');
const config = require('./module-federation.config');
module.exports = withModuleFederation(config);
```

## module-federation.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'shell',
  remotes: [],
//added shared in hope to fix problem
  shared: {
    firebase: {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: '9.17.1',
      import: 'firebase/app',
    }
  },
};
```

After adding *shared* in `module-federation.config.js` i got some other error and my app would even start: `TypeError: sharedFn is not a function`

If anyone got similar problem i would like to hear suggestions on how to fix this nonsense.

After adding shared i tried installing *devkit*, following chatGPT instructions but i got some even worse problems. Tried changing some versions of firebase but same thing.